# Creating jpa entities of several types

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, jpa

My project has 3 types of users. One type has all attributes of the other two types. I have a entity call User. And I extended UserType1 and UserType2 from User. And I want all properties of Type1 and Type2 to be there in Type3. How can I do it in JPA entities.

Comment: Providing some of your existing code will be really helpful!

Comment: extends to your entity, otherwise go for @Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.JOINED) annotation provided by JPA interface

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Java does not support multiple inheritence .  So you cannot extend both Type1 and Type2 in Type3. 
    You can use  **Embedded Objects  aka Components** .
    @Entity
    public class Order {
       @Id private Long id;
       public Long getId() { return id; }
       public void setId(Long id) { this.id = id; }

```
   @Embedded private Address address;
   public Address getAddress() { return address; }
   public void setAddress() { this.address = address; }
}

@Entity
public class User {
   private Long id;
   @Id public Long getId() { return id; }
   public void setId(Long id) { this.id = id; }

   private Address address;
   @Embedded public Address getAddress() { return address; }
   public void setAddress() { this.address = address; }
}

@Embeddable
@Access(AcessType.PROPERTY)
public class Address {
   private String street1;
   public String getStreet1() { return street1; }
   public void setStreet1() { this.street1 = street1; }

   private hashCode; //not persistent
}
```

Since you have to embed two entities then you have to use  @AttributeOverrides to override only certain fields and UserType1 and UserType2 both extend User.
@AttributeOverrides,  requires that each attribute be individually overridden.